# Converting vb to c# json

Tags: c#, vb.net

i have a hard time converting my vb .net application to .net.
Here is my vb code that i try to convert

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
            request.Method = ("GET")

            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Dim read = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            Dim raw As String = read.ReadToEnd

            Dim dict As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of List(Of Object))(raw)
            For Each item As Object In dict
                MsgBox(item("somenameinjson"))
```

I've done so far in c# but i can't figure out the for each loop from vb so i can read values from my json

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);

            request.Method = ("GET");

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            var read = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string raw = read.ReadToEnd();

            var dict = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<List<object>>(raw);
```

i managed to get it working by using this,is json array btw, thanks

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            foreach (var item in ((JArray)obj))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.Value<string>("somejsonentry"));
```

Comment: *converting my vb .net application to .net.* You mean from VB.Net (a .Net language) to C# (a .Net language). The first line is `HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);`. Method "GET" is the default. Then you have `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`. The rest is the same, except it's badly written so you'll have to rewrite to work correctly: don't use `object`, for example. You may have better results using `dynamic`, but I suggest to deserialize to classes using Json.Net. Many examples around. Dispose of the objects you create (WebResponse, Stream)

Comment: I'm guessing you have option strict off? If you're using late binding in VB.NET, you'll probably need to use `dynamic` or `ExpandoObject` in C# if you don't create a strongly typed model to deserialize to.

Answer (score 1):

#### Doing the request and getting the JSON response

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var json = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

This implementation is better because:

- You don't have to dispose your objects
- HttpClient is new API to manage WebRequests
- You use asyn/await so your CPU can execute other jobs

As Craid commented, if you use `await` keyword, you have to mark you method as `async`. In this case, you should **avoid** the signature `async void` and use `async Task` even though you return nothing

#### Parsing the JSON and iterate it

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(json);
for(var item in items)
   MsgBox(((dynamic)item).somenameinjson)
```

This implementation is better because:

- The Newtonsoft Json converter is the default library in new projects (for example .NET Core) to manage JSON
- It's faster

As Jimi said, it's better to create a model and parse that json into that model, however you can use `dynamic` too.

Comment: i am getting error using this   
string uristring = "myjsoonlink.php";
            Uri uri = new Uri(uristring);

            var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.

Comment: If you use async/await you have to change your method signature and mark it as async, example: ``public async void GetJson()``

Comment: Note that `async void` should be reserved for event handlers.  You should convert non-async `void` routines to `async Task`.